# Gitlab Registry: login inconsistency

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, docker-registry, gitlab-ce

I've an on-prem instance of Gitlab-CE 13.0.5 running, I'm using the official docker image of Gitlab.
I've enabled the integrated container registry.

Testing the login and push at the registry using a personal access token works, both on the commandline and within a CI script.

Using the CI job token in a CI script, the docker login passes, the docker push fails.

Using a group access token (with the read and write registry privilege), both login and then of course also push fails. Testing the group access token manually on the commandline the login step also fails.

I've  checked the logfile of the registry, I only see the access denied message, no further hint whats might be wrong.

I've considered to tag the image with the correct hiearchy of group and project name.

Has anyone an idea where I should continue to search?

Thanks and cheers
Wolfgang

Comment: Using the $CI_JOB_TOKEN, from the documentation[1]: "Your jobs can access all container images that you would normally have access to. The only implication is that you can push to the Container Registry of the project for which the job is triggered. " Are you trying to push to another projects registry? 1. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/new_ci_build_permissions_model.html#container-registry

Comment: Well, I was hoping again ... since I actually found rogue tab at the end of the image tag ... however, removing this tab and trying again with the CI_JOB_TOKEN doesn't change the behaviour: login passes, push fails with "denied: requested access to the resource is denied, unauthorized: authentication required".

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found it!

If there is a port number in the registry name in the login command, exactly the same name including the port number has to be used when tagging and pushing an image.

So, if in the gitlab configuration in the variable `gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = "443"`  the default port number 443 is mentioned, it appears in the variable $CI_REGISTRY and you have to use it in the tag and the push command.

Setting the variable `gitlab_rails['registry_port'] = ""` to an empty string let the system still use the port 443 - since it is the default port. However, it will be removed from the name.

To be honest, I was a bit surprised.